# SMTP connect() failed PHPmailer - PHP

Tags: php, email

I am new to PHP. I was trying to send myself a sample e-mail through PHPmailer. I am using gmail's smtp server. I am trying to send a sample mail from my gmail account to my yahoo account. But I am getting the error : `Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.` 
Here is the code :

```
<?php

require "class.phpmailer.php";
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP();                              // send via SMTP
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                       // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";        // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "mypassword";               // SMTP password
$webmaster_email = "myemail@gmail.com";       //Reply to this email ID
$email="myyahoomail@yahoo.in";                // Recipients email ID
$name="My Name";                              // Recipient's name
$mail->From = $webmaster_email;
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->FromName = "My Name";
$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"My Name");
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                         // set word wrap
$mail->IsHTML(true);                          // send as HTML
$mail->Subject = "subject";
$mail->Body = "Hi,
This is the HTML BODY ";                      //HTML Body 
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body 

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

I am using WAMP server on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. What could be the prob?
Please help me solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Just to let you know, [require](http://php.net/require) is a language construct and `()` aren't neccessary.

Comment: @RPM Thanks! I changed it. But, Please help me solve this problem

Comment: I think you missed server details details

Comment: @Krishna Please tell me what details I should add.

Comment: Where is host parameter in your code ?

Comment: @Krishna I added it just now. `$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add the `Host` parameter

```
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
```

Also, check if you have `open_ssl` enabled.

```
<?php
echo !extension_loaded('openssl')?"Not Available":"Available";
```

Comment: I added the parameter but it shows the same error `Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.`.

Comment: Is machine connected to Internet ?

Comment: @Krishna Yes my PC is connected to the Internet

Comment: I added the extension available line and it shows `Not Available`. How do I make it work?

Comment: Well, that's why it didn't work , Open your `php.ini` and search for this line `;extension=php_openssl.dll` and remove the semi colon before it , save the file and restart your webserver. You will see your coding working after you do this change.

Comment: openssl is ``available`` but it doesn't work! and I know my cpanel ISP must be cpanel/WHM but I using simple cpanel server

Comment: I just wanted to thank @ShankarDamodaran for your answer. It saved me! Thanks

Answer (score 29):

The solution of this problem is really very simple. actually Google start using a new authorization mechanism for its User.. you might have seen another line in debug console prompting you to log into your account using any browser.! this is because of new **XOAUTH2** authentication mechanism which google start using since 2014.
remember.. do not use the **ssl over port 465**, instead go for **tls over 587**. this is just because of XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism. if you use ssl over 465, your request will be bounced back.

what you really need to do is .. log into your google account and open up following address
https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
and check **turn on** . you have to do this for letting you to connect with the google SMTP because according to new authentication mechanism google bounce back all the requests from all those applications which does not follow any standard encryption technique.. after checking turn on.. you are good to go.. 
here is the code which worked fine for me..

```
require_once 'C:\xampp\htdocs\email\vendor\autoload.php';

define ('GUSER','youremail@gmail.com');
define ('GPWD','your password');


// make a separate file and include this file in that. call this function in that file.

function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->Username = GUSER;  
    $mail->Password = GPWD;           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. +100 for your answer. I had gone through all the gmail settings and spend my whole day but only start working once i turn off less secure apps option

Comment: appologies turn on and one more thing i have used 465 with ssl and i have't face any bounce back from gmail.

Comment: I love you "do not use the ssl over port 465, instead go for tls over 587". I lost so many hours....

Comment: Thanks after hours of looking found your contribution here

Answer (score 17):

Solved an almost identical problem, by adding these lines to the standard PHPMailer configuration. Works like a charm.

```
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;   
$mail->Mailer = “smtp”; // don't change the quotes!
```

Came across this code (from Simon Chen) while researching a solution here, https://webolio.wordpress.com/2008/03/02/phpmailer-and-smtp-on-1and1-shared-hosting/#comment-89

Comment: looks like this command solved the issue; mainly only the second command was necessary. It is interesting that my gmail account is filtering as spam the received email.

Comment: This should be okay. But it's not a proper solution. Received emails are tagged as spam. Better use a PHP framework to send emails with SMTP.

Comment: DON'T do this, this makes it NOT work with SMTP at all, its just sent by your host that's why you get the illusion that its working

Comment: Thanks! this did the trick. $mail->Mailer = “smtp”;

Answer (score 7):

[Troubleshooting](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

You have add this code:

```
 $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
```

And Enabling [Allow less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1): 
"will usually solve the problem for PHPMailer, and it does not really make your app significantly less secure. Reportedly, changing this setting may take an hour or more to take effect, so don't expect an immediate fix"

This work for me!

Answer (score 4):

```php
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;   
$mail->isSendMail(); // instead of  isSMTP();
```

On shared hosting, your mail server may occasionally experience connection issues.
[Here I found solution](https://webolio.wordpress.com/2008/03/02/phpmailer-and-smtp-on-1and1-shared-hosting/)

[Edit]

Here is the link content, in case the link stop working for some reason (it happens)

`PHPMailer` and `SMTP` on **1and1** shared hosting

I use `PHPMailer` on my **1and1** shared hosting account. Recently, I could not send email anymore.

I tried debugging and this is the error that `PHPMailer` throws:

> Language string failed to load: connect_host

After googling for a solution and trying different SMTP servers, accounts and SMTP ports, I decided to switch to `sendmail` and it worked like a charm! All I needed to do was to replace `$mail->isSmtp()` with:

```php
$mail->isSendMail()
```

`sendMail` is located in its default location on **1and1** servers : `/usr/sbin/sendmail`, so no change of settings was required.

### Conclusion:

**1and1** probably closed its outgoing SMTP ports on its shared hosting servers. Consequently, if you use `PHPMailer`, don’t use SMTP mode anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure you passed the right parameters
eg. the correct outgoing server host, username, and password

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->Host = 'email_smtp_host'
$mail->SMTPAuth = false
$mail->Username = 'username'
$mail->Password = 'password'
$mail->SMTPSecure 'tls'
$mail->Port = '587'
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still unable to solve the issue, please check following thread and follow callmebob's answer.

[PHPMailer - SMTP ERROR: Password command failed when send mail from my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937586/phpmailer-smtp-error-password-command-failed-when-send-mail-from-my-server#answer-25175234)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it ...

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable

```html
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'm7@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'pass';                           // SMTP password
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('m7@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('dot@gmail.com', 'User');     // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Turn on access and enjoy..! That is on Gmail account setting.

[image: Turn On access]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the directive that states the connection uses SSL

```
require ("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn of SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "YAHOO ACCOUNT";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "YAHOO ACCOUNT PASSWORD"; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "YAHOO HOST"; // SMTP host
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Then add in the other parts

```
$webmaster_email = "myemail@gmail.com";       //Reply to this email ID
$email="myyahoomail@yahoo.in";                // Recipients email ID
$name="My Name";                              // Recipient's name
$mail->From = $webmaster_email;
$mail->FromName = "My Name";
$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"My Name");
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                         // set word wrap
$mail->IsHTML(true);                          // send as HTML
$mail->Subject = "subject";
$mail->Body = "Hi,
This is the HTML BODY ";                      //HTML Body 
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body 

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

As a side note, I have had trouble using Body + AltBody together although they are supposed to work.  As a result, I wrote the following wrapper function which works perfectly.

```
<?php
require ("class.phpmailer.php");

// Setup Configuration for Mail Server Settings
$email['host']          = 'smtp.email.com';
$email['port']          = 366;
$email['user']          = 'from@email.com';
$email['pass']          = 'from password';
$email['from']          = 'From Name';
$email['reply']         = 'replyto@email.com';
$email['replyname']     = 'Reply To Name';

$addresses_to_mail_to = 'email1@email.com;email2@email.com';
$email_subject = 'My Subject';
$email_body = '<html>Code Here</html>';
$who_is_receiving_name = 'John Smith';

$result = sendmail(
    $email_body,
    $email_subject,
    $addresses_to_mail_to,
    $who_is_receiving_name
);

var_export($result);


function sendmail($body, $subject, $to, $name, $attach = "") {

  global $email;
  $return = false;

  $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
  $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
  try {
    $mail->Host       = $email['host']; // SMTP server
//    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host       = $email['host']; // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = $email['port'];                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Username   = $email['user']; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = $email['pass'];        // SMTP account password
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email['reply'], $email['replyname']);
    if(stristr($to,';')) {
      $totmp = explode(';',$to);
      foreach($totmp as $destto) {
        if(trim($destto) != "") {
          $mail->AddAddress(trim($destto), $name);
        }
      }
    } else {
      $mail->AddAddress($to, $name);
    }
    $mail->SetFrom($email['user'], $email['from']);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    if(is_array($attach)) {
        foreach($attach as $attach_f) {
            if($attach_f != "") {
              $mail->AddAttachment($attach_f);      // attachment
            }
        }
    } else {
        if($attach != "") {
          $mail->AddAttachment($attach);      // attachment
        }
    }
    $mail->Send();
  } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    $return = $e->errorMessage();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $return = $e->errorMessage();
  }

  return $return;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. I am trying to send an e-mail from my gmail account TO my yahoo account not vice-versa. Correct me if I'm wrong but I should give the username and password of my gmail account and not my yahoo account.

Comment: Correct, you would put in your GMail account credentials. Give me a moment, and I will update the function so you can use that :)

Comment: Thanks Sanuel. I got it working now. +1 for helping me. I am interested in the function. Please update it.

Comment: Function has been updated.  It allows for attaching files as well, but you must attach using the full path.  $attach can be set to one value (aka $attach = '/home/somefile.txt')  or it can be an array of files ( $attach = Array( '/home/somefile1.txt', '/home/somefile2.txt' ) ).

Comment: The only quirk I had, is for some reason, if i add a parameter to the function  (aka, $ssl), I can not use that value as the value for `$mail->SMTPSecure`  (aka, `$ssl = "tls";` then `$mail->SMTPSecure = $ssl` doesn't work... so if you need to switch, just set that line directly.

Answer (score 1):

if everything fails then  for gmail you must turn on access to 3rd party apps to connect to ur gmail account.

> https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps    // turn it
>   on

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VPS and with httpd service, please check if your httpd_can_sendmail is on.

```
getsebool -a | grep mail
```

to set on

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your script. This worked for me!

`$mail->Mailer = “smtp”;`

Comment: DON'T do this, this makes it NOT work with SMTP at all, its just sent by your host that's why you get the illusion that its working

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a result of the server not accepting SSLv2 or SSLv3 connections which is a standard for cPanel/WHM in favor of TLS only connections. You can check this by going to WHM>>Service Configuration>>Exim Configuration Manager -> Options for OpenSSL

Answer (score 0):

```
 $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
```

Comment: Please explain why/how this solves the problem. See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require_once "PHPMailer/src/Exception.php";
require_once "PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php";
require_once "PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php";



$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail ->isSMTP();
$mail ->Host ="smtp.gmail.com";
$mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
$mail ->Username = 'youremail@gmail.com';
$mail ->Password = 'password';
//$mail ->SMTPSecure=PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
$mail ->Port = '587';
$mail ->SMTPSecure ='tls';
$mail ->isHTML(true);

$mail ->setFrom('youremail@gmail.com','email send name');

$mail ->addAddress('receiver@gmail.com');
$mail ->Subject = 'HelloWorld';
$mail ->Body = 'a test email';


$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);



if ($mail->send()){
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}else{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

make sure that you configure less secure app settings in gmail using this link https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and make sure you downloaded PHPMailer-master.zip from github

working fine with MAMP server locally :)

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching, I found out that the protocol name needs to be in lowercase.

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; # lowercase
```

Answer (score 0):

find the "class.smtp.php" file
original:

```
$this->smtp_conn =fsockopen(
$host,
$port,
$errno,
$errstr,
$timeout
);
```

change to:

```
$this->smtp_conn = @stream_socket_client(
$host,
$port,
$errno,
$errstr,
$timeout
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the virus guard blocks the mail. If it is turn off and try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).