# PHPMailer SMTP connect() failed not work for other address

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp

I use `phpmailer` to send messages. I used with my Gmail account to be sent ok, but When I change account on other (new account) I gets an error.

```
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Username and password are correct. I must something change in my mail settings?

Code:

```
<?php
require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'pass';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                                   // TCP port to connect to
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], 'Wiadomosc');
$mail->addAddress('xyz@gmail.com', '');     // Add a recipient

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Wiadomość ze strony Akademia Uwodzenia';
$mail->Body    = 'Imię: '.$_POST['imie'].'<br>Nazwisko: '.$_POST['nazwisko'].'<br>Wiadomość: '.$_POST['wiadomosc'].'';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

I have openssl. Sending works for my gmail account. After the data is changed to another account - company account. The code is not working.

Message from SMTP Debug

```
    2016-01-09 11:22:08 Connection: opening to ssl://173.194.220.108:465, 
timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2016-01-09 11:22:08  Connection: opened 2016-01-
09 11:22:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP b74sm14107051lfb.32 - 
gsmtp 2016-01-09 11:22:08   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2016-01-09 11:22:08    
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [158.75.89.196] 250-SIZE 
35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER 
XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 2016-01-
09 11:22:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2016-01-09 11:22:08    SERVER -> 
CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 2016-01-09 11:22:08    CLIENT -> SERVER: 
Yml1cm91d29kemVuaWFAZ21haWwuY29t 2016-01-09 11:22:08    SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 
UGFzc3dvcmQ6 2016-01-09 11:22:08    CLIENT -> SERVER: a29iaWV0YTkw 2016-01-09 
11:22:09    SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and
 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 b74sm14107051lfb.32 - gsmtp 2016-
01-09 11:22:09  SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in 
via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534
 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 b74sm14107051lfb.32 - gsmtp 
2016-01-09 11:22:09 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2016-01-09 11:22:09 
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2016-01-09 11:22:09  SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing 
connection b74sm14107051lfb.32 - gsmtp 2016-01-09 11:22:09  Connection: closed 
2016-01-09 11:22:09 SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be 
sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Problem solved:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMTP connect() failed PHPmailer - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927634/smtp-connect-failed-phpmailer-php)

Comment: I have openssl. Sending works for my gmail account. After the data is changed to another account - company account. The code is not working.