# While send form, phpMailer problems

Tags: phpmailer

I want to send some information on form in goverment website. But when submit, this error: 
" SMTP Connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting "
What is this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMTP connect() failed PHPmailer - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927634/smtp-connect-failed-phpmailer-php)

Comment: Have you considered following that link?