# PHPMailer don't send e-mail

Tags: php, api, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to send mail over PHPMailer. Since 10 days PHPMailer don't send e-mail and throw an exception:

```
{
    "code": "ERROR",
    "message": "SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting"
}
```

This is below my code: It was working

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

        try {
            // Server settings
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host       = 'localhost';
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = false;
            $mail->Port       = 25;
            // Recipients
            $mail->setFrom($this->mailAddress, $this->mailName);
            $mail->addAddress($email);
            // Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = 'Réinitialisation du mot de passe';
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
            $mail->Encoding = 'base64';
            $mail->Body    = 'test';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
        }

        return $mail->send();
```

I tried to upgrade PHPMailer to 6.1.7. I thought that PHPMailer had a security issues according to `packagist`.

Can someone help me to fix this error

Comment: Have you tried following the troubleshooting steps at the link shown in your error message? It can't connect to the SMTP server on your localhost. Make sure the smtp server is running and that you're not running it on a non-default port.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SMTP connect() failed PHPmailer - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927634/smtp-connect-failed-phpmailer-php)

Comment: I'm using Exchange adresse mail. How can i verify that my SMTP server is running on my localhost. I'm using it with docker containor

Answer (score 0):

Check this post
[SMTP connect() failed PHPmailer - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927634/smtp-connect-failed-phpmailer-php)