# PHPMailer not working in my server

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, phpmailer, sendmail

I built a droplet with Ubuntu with DigitalOcean and I'm trying to configure it to send emails with SMTP.

I know DigitalOcean blocks SMTP over IPv6 but not over IPv4 so I disabled IPv6 as [this post says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04).

My script still doesn't work. I've tried with ports 25, 465 and 587. TLS and SSL.

I've installed `sendmail` for Ubuntu 14.04 but not working.

This is my script:

```
<?php
    require 'mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    
    $to = $_GET['email'];
    
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'rafawins@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '***';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    
    $mail->setFrom('rafawins@gmail.com', 'Rafael');
    
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    
    $mail->Subject = 'Subject';
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    $mail->Body    = "ao!";
    
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
    print_r(error_get_last());
    

?>
```

The error presented is:

> SMTP connect() failed.

I'm interested in sending email **using SMTP** so `->isSMTP()` is required!

Where am I wrong?

Thank you very much.

---

**EDIT:**

doing: `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`
I get:

> Trying 74.125.133.108...
>
> Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
>
> Escape character is '^]'.
>
> 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP w6sm13897014wjy.31 - gsmtp

and doing: `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465` I get an answer as well...

What's wrong?

Comment: You need to define "not working". Read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), post what you get with `SMTPDebug = 4`.

Comment: Sorry I updated the error. I forgot to write it! I've been in the troubleshooting guide before. Otherwise I wouldn't have come to StackOverflow :)

Comment: So post what you get from debug output, like the guide says - there are over 800 questions on SO about that exact message. It's very, very likely you're running into a problem that is described exactly in the guide; connecting to gmail is pretty messy these days.

Comment: SMTP Ports are blocked by default on OceanDigital, you must open a support ticket to enable SMTP ports.

Comment: try "tls" to "ssl" some times server need ssl.

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos it's unlocked for IPv4 as I said.

Comment: @ravipatel I tried as I said

Comment: Ocean blocks ipv4 also. You must request it for the support team. If you already did it, have you tried to telnet the gmail smtp server from your vps ? You can test using the following command: `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`

If everything still ok, please share the debug information...

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos I got that ticket and I was answered that IPv6 is blocked, but not IPv4. That's why I'm writing here :).
  `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` works ok

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Port 465 (SSL required)
Port 587 (TLS required)

Comment: @ravipatel not solved :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware of using Gmail from different devices. google doesn't allow and block immediately a location from where an account is used where it isn't supposed to use (in the eyes of google ofcourse).

Comment: you can run your code from `localhost` though. also check your inbox for any notification you might receive regarding suspension of your account for that particular device/ip

Comment: the same script has been used in an AWS server and it works OK. So the problem is here

Comment: so you have been using this account from different devices (at different hosting sites) at different geo-locations.  have you checked your inbox too?

Comment: yes. I'm trying with different servers and I can do it perfectly, even from different accounts. But not in this server (DigitalOcean)

Comment: you were right, I got information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937586/phpmailer-smtp-error-password-command-failed-when-send-mail-from-my-server and solved my question

Answer (score 1):

On live server for send Mail using SMTP, Do it.

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
```

and Comment $mail->IsSMTP();

It's Working For Me....

Comment: this might be working, but it is then using the default mail function, not the SMTP Server

Answer (score -1):

Try commenting out line 8.

```
// $mail->isSMTP();
```

Comment: This will ignore all your SMTP settings and send emails using the webserver.