# Unable to send email in php

Tags: php

I am trying following code to send mail
but it is showing

```
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

and gmail is informing me that Sign-in attempt prevented

```
 <?php
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'sss@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = '*******';
     $mail->Port =  587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
     $mail->From = 'abc@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'asdf ';
    $mail->addAddress('abc@gmail.com', 'sadf ');

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = "Using PHPMailer";
    $mail->Body    = "Hi Iam using PHPMailer library to sent SMTP mail from localhost";

    if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo "Message could not be sent.";
       echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }

    echo "Message has been sent";
    ?>
```

How to resolve above problem?

Comment: Does the firewall of your host have port 587 outgoing open?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried port 465 and 25 **with** ssl?

Comment: yes both port is showing same problem

Comment: Is above code is correct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27982826/876739 this solved my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer - SMTP ERROR: Password command failed when send mail from my server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937586/phpmailer-smtp-error-password-command-failed-when-send-mail-from-my-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting email from Google, it describes the email is trying to send but it is blocked by Google. Do the following steps.

I hope this helps.

1. [Check if IMAP is enabled](https://support.google.com/a/answer/105694?hl=en)
2. [Check here and enable less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
3. [Display Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

Answer (score 2):

You need set permission for send mail with **gmail**.

**- Login Google Account 

- Go Privacy Page

- Allow third party apps**

After try this code:

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");


if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Done still same message

Comment: Ah ok, i have the same problem but with Allow third party apps i solved.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following steps:

- enable debug mode to catch possible errors

  ```
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
  ```
- enable SMTP authentication

  ```
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  ```
- also check for SSL support in php configuration file (`php.ini`)

  ```
  extension=php_openssl.dll
  ```

Answer (score 1):

change the following in your code

`isSMTP()` to `IsSMTP()` , `addAddress()` to `AddAddress()`  & `isHTML()` to `IsHTML()`.

and yes check the ports also. sometoimes port also off which do not let connection to be established.

Hope it will work!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to enable POP and IMAP in you gamil. Try this

- Sign in to Gmail
- Click the gear in the top right.
- Select Settings.
- Click    Forwarding and POP/IMAP.
- Select Enable    IMAP.
- Click Save      Changes.

```html
<?
$account="email_address@gmail.com";
$password="accountpassword";
$to="mail@subinsb.com";
$from="email_address@gmail.com";
$from_name="Name";
$msg="<strong>This is a bold text.</strong>"; // HTML message
$subject="Database Backup";
/*End Config*/

include("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth= true;
$mail->Port = 465; // Or 587
$mail->Username= $account;
$mail->Password= $password;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName= $from_name;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $msg;
$mail->addAddress($to);
if(!$mail->send()){
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
 echo "E-Mail has been sent";
}
?>
```