# PHPMailer: Sending Failed

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, contact-form, smtp-auth

Im trying to make a contact form, I searched alot on the web but didn't found any solution that works.

This is contact-form HTML and PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  $message=
      'Name:    '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
  Subject:  '.$_POST['message'].'<br />
  Email:    '.$_POST['email'].'
  ';

  require 'class.phpmailer.php';
  require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

  // Instantiate Class
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  // Set up SMTP
  $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require     authorization
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";      // Connect using a TLS connection
  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
  $mail->Port = 587;  //Gmail SMTP port

  // Authentication
  $mail->Username   = '**********@gmail.com'; // Your full Gmail address
  $mail->Password   = '**********'; // Your Gmail password

  $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
  // Compose
  $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
  $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
  $mail->Subject = "New Contact Form Enquiry";      // Subject (which isn't required)
  $mail->MsgHTML($message);

  // Send To
  $mail->AddAddress("*********@gmail.com", "Recipient Name"); // Where to send it - Recipient
  $result = $mail->Send();      // Send!
  $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';
  unset($mail);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div style="margin: 100px auto 0;width: 300px;">
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    <form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <p><?php if(!empty($message)) echo $message; ?></p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I get this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kruY6.png).
I have the latest version of PHPMailer, Username and Password are correct.

Can someone please help?

Comment: If u r using   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  than chk yur user email and password are correct or not?

Comment: Or create a new email user and use it for testing

Comment: $mail->IsMail(); That way you don't need to use smtp and gmail. Works perfectly!

Comment: @devpro Thanks.. just created a new account and it was fixed. Don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: @ChrisG I tried with the IsMail() but had error 'Could not instantiate mail function'

Comment: Hahahah... congrats well u can also reset the pswrd

Comment: Well plz share the solution with others it will help to others ..

Comment: Search before posting - this has been answered hundreds of times before, and this exact problem is covered in the troubleshooting guide that the error message links to. Really, just read what the message says, we're not here to do your thinking for you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer - SMTP ERROR: Password command failed when send mail from my server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937586/phpmailer-smtp-error-password-command-failed-when-send-mail-from-my-server)