# PHPMailer and Zurb Foundation for emails (Headers already sent)

Tags: php, html, css, email

I am still new to both phpmailer so I tried to implement [zurb foundation framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html) to design my email template and did [this](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/css-guide.html#inlining) as suggested in the documentation. The **email were sent successfully** but i get this warning and these `CLIENT -> SERVER:` that prints out all the html code on the `$mail->Body` tag instead of redirecting to an html page after the email was sent:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vendors\phpmailer\class.smtp.php:234)

Below is my code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
//Turning peer verification off
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "password";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('email@gmail.com', 'Account');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress($email, $name);
$mail->isHTML(true);
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Test';
$mail->Body = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"><title>Title</title></head><body style="-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;Margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;min-width:100%;padding:0;text-align:left;width:100%!important"><style>@media only screen{html{min-height:100%;background:#f3f3f3}}@media only screen and (max-width:596px){.small-float-center{margin:0 auto!important;float:none!important;text-align:center!important}.small-text-center{text-align:center!important}.small-text-left{text-align:left!important}.small-text-right{text-align:right!important}}@media only screen and (max-width:596px){.hide-for-large{display:block!important;width:auto!important;overflow:visible!important;max-height:none!important;font-size:inherit!important;line-height:inherit!important}}@media only screen and (max-width:596px){table.body table.container .hide-for-large,table.body table.container .row.hide-for-large{display:table!important;width:100%!important}}@media only screen and (max-width:596px){table.body table.container .callout-inner.hide-for-large{display:table-cell!important;width:100%!important}}@media only screen and (max-width:596px){table.body table.container .show-for-large{display:none!important;width:0;mso-hide:all;overflow:hidden}}@media only screen and (max-width:596px){table.body img{width:auto;height:auto}table.body center{min-width:0!important}table.body .container{width:95%!important}table.body .column,table.body .columns{height:auto!important;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding-left:16px!important;padding-right:16px!important}table.body .column .column,table.body .column .columns,table.body .columns .column,table.body .columns .columns{padding-left:0!important;padding-right:0!important}table.body .collapse .column,table.body .collapse .columns{padding-left:0!important;padding-right:0!important}td.small-1,th.small-1{display:inline-block!important;width:8.33333%!important}td.small-2,th.small-2{display:inline-block!important;width:16.66667%!important}td.small-3,th.small-3{display:inline-block!important;width:25%!important}td.small-4,th.small-4{display:inline-block!important;width:33.33333%!important}td.small-5,th.small-5{display:inline-block!important;width:41.66667%!important}td.small-6,th.small-6{display:inline-block!important;width:50%!important}td.small-7,th.small-7{display:inline-block!important;width:58.33333%!important}td.small-8,th.small-8{display:inline-block!important;width:66.66667%!important}td.small-9,th.small-9{display:inline-block!important;width:75%!important}td.small-10,th.small-10{display:inline-block!important;width:83.33333%!important}td.small-11,th.small-11{display:inline-block!important;width:91.66667%!important}td.small-12,th.small-12{display:inline-block!important;width:100%!important}.column td.small-12,.column th.small-12,.columns td.small-12,.columns th.small-12{display:block!important;width:100%!important}table.body td.small-offset-1,table.body th.small-offset-1{margin-left:8.33333%!important;Margin-left:8.33333%!important}table.body td.small-offset-2,table.body th.small-offset-2{margin-left:16.66667%!important;Margin-left:16.66667%!important}table.body td.small-offset-3,table.body th.small-offset-3{margin-left:25%!important;Margin-left:25%!important}table.body td.small-offset-4,table.body th.small-offset-4{margin-left:33.33333%!important;Margin-left:33.33333%!important}table.body td.small-offset-5,table.body th.small-offset-5{margin-left:41.66667%!important;Margin-left:41.66667%!important}table.body td.small-offset-6,table.body th.small-offset-6{margin-left:50%!important;Margin-left:50%!important}table.body td.small-offset-7,table.body th.small-offset-7{margin-left:58.33333%!important;Margin-left:58.33333%!important}table.body td.small-offset-8,table.body th.small-offset-8{margin-left:66.66667%!important;Margin-left:66.66667%!important}table.body td.small-offset-9,table.body th.small-offset-9{margin-left:75%!important;Margin-left:75%!important}table.body td.small-offset-10,table.body th.small-offset-10{margin-left:83.33333%!important;Margin-left:83.33333%!important}table.body td.small-offset-11,table.body th.small-offset-11{margin-left:91.66667%!important;Margin-left:91.66667%!important}table.body table.columns td.expander,table.body table.columns th.expander{display:none!important}table.body .right-text-pad,table.body .text-pad-right{padding-left:10px!important}table.body .left-text-pad,table.body .text-pad-left{padding-right:10px!important}table.menu{width:100%!important}table.menu td,table.menu th{width:auto!important;display:inline-block!important}table.menu.small-vertical td,table.menu.small-vertical th,table.menu.vertical td,table.menu.vertical th{display:block!important}table.menu[align=center]{width:auto!important}table.button.small-expand,table.button.small-expanded{width:100%!important}table.button.small-expand table,table.button.small-expanded table{width:100%}table.button.small-expand table a,table.button.small-expanded table a{text-align:center!important;width:100%!important;padding-left:0!important;padding-right:0!important}table.button.small-expand center,table.button.small-expanded center{min-width:0}}</style><table class="body" data-made-with-foundation="" style="Margin:0;background:#f3f3f3;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;height:100%;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%"><tbody><tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"><td class="float-center" align="center" valign="top" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0 auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;float:none;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><center style="min-width:580px;width:100%"></center></td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>';
if (!$mail->send()) {
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   header("Location:login.php?login=success");
   exit();
}
```

How am i supposed to actually wrap the codes on zurb foundation inside phpmailer's `$mail->body`?

Comment: put a semi-colon `;` after this line `$mail->Body  = .......................`

Comment: @Rafiq oops that was a typing error. i have `;` inside my code. it did send the email. but it gives me that warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `$mail->Debugoutput = 'error_log';` instead of `$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';` will solve your problem.

`header()`  function must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. If any actual output is sent before `header()`  function call then `Headers already sent` error occur.  So when you use `$mail->Debugoutput` as `html`  it generate output and error is is generated. But `error_log` is not outputed, it log error in file. For more details you can see [php:header manual](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.header.php)  or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/2151290)

**If you are not able to send mail using gmail smtp try the following**

Use the following link to give captcha(if any) and give permission to Access for less secure apps in gmail:

- [Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)
- [Turn on Access for less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security/lesssecureapps)
- [Recently used devices](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?hl=en&pli=1)

See [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25175234/2151290)

Comment: i think you get me wrong. i want to implement zurb foundation framework.  i have this system when a user click that button, it will send an email and redirect the user to the login page. in my case, it did send the email successfully just like i wanted it's just it doesnt redirect to login page and display me warning instead

Comment: Use `$mail->Debugoutput = 'error_log';` instead of `$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';` will solve your problem.

Comment: it worked thank you! But can you explain why? Because i am still new to phpmailer.

Comment: and also, why did that warning occur? Is it okay if i should just ignore it?

Comment: `header()`  function must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. If any actual output is sent before `header()`  function call then `Headers already sent` error occur.  So when you use `$mail->Debugoutput` as `html`  it generate output and error is is generated. But `error_log` is not outputed, it log error in file. For more details you can see [php:header manual](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.header.php)  or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/2151290)