# SMTP Error : Could not authenticate PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, post, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to create a contact form on my website with PHPMailer. The issue is that when I try it on my local server (with Wampserver), the email is sent but when I try it on the hosted server I get the SMTP Error : Could not authenticate.
I created a fresh new gmail account to send my emails, I enabled the less-security access and I don't have any sorts of 2-Step authentification.

I use an external php file to create the template of the mail, here is the code :
[image]

I use the switch to get emails from differents forms, as I would eventually need to send differents types of mail which would require different fields or templates.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Enable phpMailer’s SMTP debug mode, and see what additional info that gets you.

Comment: It's very likely that [this will help](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps).

Comment: @CBroe Thank you ! As I begin with PHPMailer I didn't know about it and it helped me to find my problem. Btw I found solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937586/phpmailer-smtp-error-password-command-failed-when-send-mail-from-my-server