# smtp connect failed phpmailer with gmail

Tags: php

I try to work with smtp of gmail, but I get error:

> 2016-08-29 11:29:03   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.*****.com 2016-08-29
>   11:29:03  CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2016-08-29 11:29:03  CLIENT ->
>   SERVER: EHLO www.*****.com 2016-08-29 11:29:03    CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH
>   LOGIN 2016-08-29 11:29:03 CLIENT -> SERVER:
>   NXN0YXJob3ZhbG90Lm9mZmVyc0BnbWFpbC5jb20= 2016-08-29 11:29:03  CLIENT ->
>   SERVER: Z2VsYTIwMTY= 2016-08-29 11:29:05  SMTP ERROR: Password command
>   failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data 2016-08-29 11:29:05 SMTP
>   Error: Could not authenticate. 2016-08-29 11:29:05    CLIENT -> SERVER:
>   QUIT 2016-08-29 11:29:05  **SMTP connect() failed.**
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

i'm using this code:

```
<?
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                       // telling the class to use SMTP

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                  
// 0 = no output, 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only.

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                // enable SMTP authentication 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";              // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";        // sets Gmail as the SMTP server
$mail->Port = 587;                     // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL 

$mail->Username = "544@gmail.com";  // Gmail username
$mail->Password = "232323";      // Gmail password

$mail->CharSet = 'windows-1250';
$mail->SetFrom ('544@gmail.com', 'Example.com Information');
$mail->AddBCC ( '544@gmail.com', 'Example.com Sales Dep.'); 
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->ContentType = 'text/plain'; 
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$body_of_your_email="ssffs";
$mail->Body = $body_of_your_email; 
// you may also use $mail->Body = file_get_contents('your_mail_template.html');

$mail->AddAddress ('544@gmail.com', 'Recipients Name');     
// you may also use this format $mail->AddAddress ($recipient);

if(!$mail->Send()) 
{
        $error_message = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else 
{
        $error_message = "Successfully sent!";
}

?>
```

Comment: I see that error at first : "SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data". Did you provide the right credentials ?

Comment: @Julqas are you mean username and password? if yes, so I put the right username and password

Comment: Yes the username and password exactly

Comment: @Julqas Yes I'm set the right username and password

Comment: What kind of server are you using to test your code ? I think this is a problem with the "security" here

Comment: @Julqas shared hosting

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297264/password-not-accepted-from-server-535-incorrect-authentication-data-when-send or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937586/phpmailer-smtp-error-password-command-failed-when-send-mail-from-my-server to see if it helps you

Comment: @Julqas not help for me...