# How can I fix curl error (51) when not run as root?

Tags: curl

When I run the following command to send email through an SMTP server, it works fine as root but does not as any other user. Domains, emails and password have been redacted.

```
curl -v -u noreply@XXXXXX.com:PASSWORD --url 'smtp://SMPT.SERVER.COM:587' --ssl-reqd \
  --mail-from 'noreply@XXXXXX.com:PASSWORD' \
  --mail-rcpt 'user@example.com' \
  --upload-file email.txt
```

The output I'm seeing from the failed request is:

```
> STARTTLS
< 220 TLS go ahead
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=server.MYSERVERDOMAIN.com,OU=PositiveSSL,OU=Domain Control Validated
*       start date: Oct 11 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*       expire date: Oct 10 23:59:59 2020 GMT
*       common name: server.MYSERVERDOMAIN.com
*       issuer: CN="cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority",O="cPanel, Inc.",L=Houston,ST=TX,C=US
* NSS error -12276 (SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN)
* Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.
```

I've tried searching high and low but nothing has worked to fix this. What's going on and how do I fix this?

Comment: is the host name proper for the cert?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a valid cert at server.MYSERVERDOMAIN.com? If so, yes and it comes back clean from online ssl checkers.

Comment: well it looks like possibly the `SMPT.SERVER.COM` is returning the cert for server.MYSERVERDOMAIN.com

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with that. Either way, why would the command work as root but not as a normal (not jailed) account user?

Comment: its a misconfiguration on the server, not locally.

Comment: I just tested that by logging into a completely different server and running the command, not as root, and it runs fine. The issue is definitely something local.

Comment: perhaps you should check out your local certifcate store and check for any updates to curl.

Comment: This ended up being a WHM/cPanel restriction. Fixed by following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297264/password-not-accepted-from-server-535-incorrect-authentication-data-when-send/44564332#44564332